# All Day Events in Calendar List View

Tags: list, calendar, view

I have a custom list with a view that utilizes one of the fields, a date field, to populate a calendar view. Pretty standard stuff. The problem is when creating a Calendar view, you need to select a start and end date and time. If the instance is an all day event, it will still show midnight next to the item.

As a note, the data field that populates the start and end date and times for the view is Date only, it has not captured any time data.

Is there a way to strip the time from the view?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, because I don't have environment now to look at the elements, but I think that you can find tag for time in html by firebug and use css or js to hide it. See this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/c7f6070b-1c91-48bf-be4d-3b4dabd8338d) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately the little date there is part of the whole tiles element, and doesn't have a tag of it's own. Very odd.

Comment: have you seen the link that I provided? It looks like the solutions in it should work.

Comment: Look at this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/sharepoint-hide-time-in-calendar-view/) too, there are a lot of pictures :)

Answer (score 1):

If the calendar is an all day-event, make sure you choose the "All Day Event" checkbox. This removes the timestamp from any event item. This is of course presumes that you are using Calendar as a parent type.

Comment: I've created a Calendar View for a custom list. There's no "All Day Event" checkbox in the properties of the view.

Comment: You need to have the Event content type as the parent of the custom list you have. That way you can have the "All Day Event" functionality to your list. My suggestion would be to enable the "management of content types" in the Advanced Settings of the list, add the Event content type, then add the custom columns to that Event instance in the list, and use that.

Comment: @Mike This wouldn't be a good solution if you have a custom list of projects and each project list item has multiple date milestones.  What would the "All Day Event" mean for a project which has more dates then just a "Start Date" and "End Date" that need to show up on the calendar?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same frustrating issues where I populated a SharePoint 2013 calendar from importing an Excel Spreadsheet list and it set an automatic Start time of 12AM. I don't know about you, but most business events don't start at Midnight. So, besides being incorrect, it was also very misleading.

Then I thought that maybe SharePoint is picking up the default time-stamp format in Excel (unseen) which is 12AM.

So I went back to my source Excel document and changed the Date format field to include the time.  Then changed the default time of 12AM to 8AM; imported it to SharePoint and it picked up the new time of 8AM.  I also changed the End date time to 5PM with the same success.

A very simple fix that doesn't require any special HTML or Source Code modifications as I have seen in other blogs related to this issue.